# XCode Validation problem

Tags: xcode

Trying to validate an Xcode project. First time around, it went fine; this time around, it claims there are no suitable records found. Yet the provisioning profiles and distribution profiles are all current, not expired, and the bundle IDs match up fine. What can be the other causes of this type of validation response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen where project files can retain, erroneously, the UIDs of old provisioning profiles. Does the error you get show a provisioning profile UID? If so, close your project, then edit the .pbxproj file looking for the UID. If there's a line (or 2 or 3) containing that line, remove it from the project file, being careful not to break the XML! You should probably save a copy of your project file somewhere before you do this, if you are unsure of what you're doing. Alternatively, you could try, using Xcode, to set through its GUI the correct provisioning profile(s) again. This *might* fixup the erroneous settings you cannot see.